# Augment R Drawdown functions to evaluate drawdowns without recovery time?

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I recently did a drawdown analysis on some historical data, but the problem was that because of how the findDrawdowns() function calculates the end of a drawdown to be after the recover time, the Great Depression ate up a lot of the time frame.

Is there an argument to pass to the function or a similar function that exists that will end each drawdown at the trough value? So essentially it would capture the drawdowns that occur within the recovery time by resetting to local min/max values for cumulative return. Essentially using a rolling time window for the drawdowns in R. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: The grawdown corresponding to the Great Depression didn't end until a new high water mark was reached.  That's the definition of a drawdown.  If we 'end at the trough', every single period dip, or run of down periods, will be a 'drawdown' which will end with a single up period.  I don't know what that is, but it isn't a 'drawdown'.